# GRUB not detecting patched kernel on Void Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, grub, initramfs, void-linux

I have a Void Linux partition on my MacBook Air. I followed [this guide](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/kernel/) to compile a patched version of Linux 6.3.7_1. I built the kernel in ~/build. Everything went well but when I reboot the kernel is not detected as an option, even after running sudo update-grub. What did I do wrong?

Edit: I added a custom menuentry. I’ll edit when I get it working.

Comment: Building the kernel is not enough. `bzImage` must be installed somewhere.

Comment: I installed vmlinuz, what do i need to do?

Comment: 1) I've no idea how Void Linux GRUB works 2) I've no idea what you did by *"I installed vmlinuz"*. That's not enough. GRUB has its configuration file, it must be updated to include the new kernel. Maybe read Void Linux GRUB documentation. There are very few people here who use this distro.

Comment: Yeah you really need to at least show the command you ran to install the patched kernel and maybe the file tree of `/boot`. Usually you don't build everything as builtin so likely there are modules that need to be installed as well. Besides, did you have the original kernel replaced or did you build it properly and / so that you can install it *in addition to* the original one?

Answer (score 0):

I added a custom menuentry which fixed it.